# Mongoose schema : SubDocument field only unique per Document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, subdocument

I have a little question. I have a User schema which contains a table fields redirecting to the Table schema.
A Table element can contain a name, I want this name to be unique per User but not between User.

Example:
User1 -> Table1.name: "foo"
User2 -> Table1.name: "foo"

But this User1 -> Table2.name: "foo" cannot be possible.

This is the User Schema:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {  type: String, required: true, index: {  
    unique: true } },
    email: {  type: String, required: true, index: {unique: true } },
    password: {  type: String, required: true },
    tables: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Table' }],
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpires: Date,
    uuid: String,                
});
```

This is the Table schema:

```
var TableSchema = Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true }},
    logos: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Logo'}],
});
```

And this is where I do the queries:

```
app.post('/newTab', function(req, res){

    var use = req.user.username;
    var newTab = new Table({
        name: req.body.name,
    });

    newTab.save(function(err, docs){
        if (err) 
        {
            console.error(err);
            res.writeHead(500);
            res.end();
        }
        else
        {
            User.findOne({username: req.user.username}, function(err,  docs) {
                if(err)  {throw (err);}
                else
                {
                    docs.tables.push(newTab);
                    docs.save(function(err, docs){
                        if (err) return console.error(err);
                        res.writeHead(200);
                        res.end(userId);
                    });
                }
            }); 
        }
    });
```

For now, I cannot add the same table name for two different User ..
I also tried something with sparse index but can't figure how it works

Comment: In the above you only have one distinct user with the username `req.user.username`, where is the other user to add the table to?

Comment: req.user.username contains the logged in user thanks to PassportJS

Comment: Yes, but in your question you are saying "I cannot add the same table name for two different User", my question is, where is the other user you are referring here to?

Comment: on my DB, when I logout and login with an other user, I cannot add a table which have the same name as the table of the previous user